# How to change program Icon programmatically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, icons, clr

how do I change the programm icon programmatically in Visual C++? My IDE is Visual Studio 2013.

I want to change the Icon to an embedded resource Icon. Do you know what to do?

Comment: I have no idea about VS2013 but isn't a program icon a static resource? I.e. you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

..

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

struct IconHandler
{
    internal const uint WmSeticon = 0x80u;
    internal const int IconSmall = 0x0;
    internal const int IconBig = 0x1;
}

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    InitializeComponent();

    //Properties.Resources.Icon.Handle is just an .*ico file in your resources. Icons can have different sizes.
    SendMessage(Handle, IconHandler.WmSeticon, IconHandler.IconSmall, Properties.Resources.Icon.Handle);
    SendMessage(Handle, IconHandler.WmSeticon, IconHandler.IconBig, Properties.Resources.Icon.Handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the program icon of Microsoft Visual Studio C++ you can:

```
Right Click Visual Studio 2013

1.Click "Properties"

2.Click the sub-tab "Shortcut"

3.Click "Change Icon"

4.Browse or select from the list below
```

Done!

Comment: No I wanted to change the icon of my program, while loading the form